# Laravel Query Builder and Eloquent query builder add an odd phrase when I try to build the query on the fly?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-livewire

I am attempting to build a query on the fly depending upon what is entered in a form.  When I do so, I check what the sql statement is in the Console.  I have OR and AND contitions, so I use a call back to build the query.  the SQL statement that results is:

```
select `id`, `activity_name`, `activity_name_web`, `year`, `season`, `sex`,
 `active_on_web`, `begin_active_on_web`, `end_active_on_web`, `begin_age`, 
`end_age`, `begin_date`, `end_date` from `activities` where (season='fall' 
OR season='summer' is null) order by `begin_date` desc, `activity_name` asc 
limit 25 offset 0 []
```

notice the words "is null".  I can't determine how this phrase is being added.

The Code:

```php
$qry_where = "1";
$arry_Season = array();
if($this->a_fall)
    $arry_Season[] = "LOWER(`season`)='fall'";

if($this->a_spring)
    $arry_Season[] = "LOWER(`season`)='spring'";

if($this->a_summer)
    $arry_Season[] = "LOWER(`season`)='summer'";

if($this->a_winter)
    $arry_Season[] = "LOWER(`season`)='winter'";

if(count($arry_Season)>0) {
    $qry_where =  $arry_Season[0];
    if(count($arry_Season)>1){
        array_shift($arry_Season);
        foreach($arry_Season as $season){
            $qry_where .= " OR " . $season;
        }
    }
}

$activities = Activity::select('id','activity_name','activity_name_web','year','season', 'sex', 'active_on_web',
    'begin_active_on_web', 'end_active_on_web', 'begin_age', 'end_age', 'begin_date','end_date')
    ->where(function($query) use ($qry_where) {
        if($qry_where == "1")
            $query->where('id','>',0);
        else {
            $query->where(DB::raw($qry_where));
        }
    })
    ->orderBy('begin_date','desc')->orderBy('activity_name','asc')
    ->paginate(25);
```

So, if the users checks the box labelled "fall", I add it to the query builder.

so - Where is the phrase "is null" coming from.

```
select `id`, `activity_name`, `activity_name_web`, `year`, `season`, `sex`,
 `active_on_web`,`begin_active_on_web`, `end_active_on_web`, `begin_age`,
 `end_age`, `begin_date`, `end_date` from `activities` 
where (season='fall' OR season='summer' is null) 
order by `begin_date` desc, `activity_name` asc limit 25 offset 0 []
```

btw, say I check fall and summer, then I ddd($qry_where) just before I build the query, I get this:

```
"LOWER(`season`)='fall' OR LOWER(`season`)='summer'"
```

I also need to mention that I am using a livewire component.

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: are you trying to filter using livewire ? is it only four checkboxes ? is it all your filters? if i understand well you have four season and if i click one season it shows activities for that season right?

Comment: ->whereRaw($qry_where);  try this instead of where(DB::raw($qry_where));

Comment: Hi,  yes there are other items on the form, and i am adding more. right now i have a year filter and a season filter, and a paginate filter (# to paginate).  and you are correct, if you click a season or seasons, it will filter the activities offered to those occuring in the chosen seasons, and year if they choose to filter by year as well.  I offer multiple seasons as a choice because often an activity crosses a season boundary, e.g. an activity might go from Feb1 thru april 1 (winter / spring).  thank you for yoru input.  it was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

You did a `where(<raw query>)` which defaults to do a `WHERE <raw query> is not NULL` since `WHERE` assumes a comparison. Here's what I think is a more concise version of your query:

```
$seasons = array_filter([ 
   $this->a_spring ? 'spring' : null,
   $this->a_summer ? 'summer' : null,
   $this->a_fall ? 'fall' : null
   $this->a_winter ? 'winter' : null
]);

$activities = Activity::select('id','activity_name','activity_name_web','year','season', 'sex', 'active_on_web',
    'begin_active_on_web', 'end_active_on_web', 'begin_age', 'end_age', 'begin_date','end_date')
    ->when(count($seasons) > 0, function($query) use ($seasons) {
         $query->whereIn(DB::raw('LOWER(season)'), $seasons);        
    })->when(count($seasons) == 0, function ($query) {
        $query->where('id', > 0);  // Not sure you need this part
    })
    ->orderBy('begin_date','desc')->orderBy('activity_name','asc')
    ->paginate(25);
```

Comment: your suggestion is poetry to my typing fingers ... thank you.  I had to tweak it a bit as the whereIn() did not like the "DB::raw()" statement as typed.  And you are correct, the second when() statement is not needed.  I just had it in there as an attempt to make this work.  I ended with this: (next comment)

Answer (score 0):

@apokryfos thank you for your quick answer. It was driving me crazy.  It seems when I passed a variable into the ->where(DB::raw()), it evaluated the variable too late for the ->when() to see that the variable contained a comparison?

In any case, I tweeked the solution that @apokryfos a bit and came up with the following:

```
$activities = Activity::select('id','activity_name','activity_name_web','year','season', 'sex', 'active_on_web',
            'begin_active_on_web', 'end_active_on_web', 'begin_age', 'end_age', 'begin_date','end_date',
            'cost_member','cost_non_member')
            ->when(count($seasons) > 0, function($query) use ($seasons) {
                $query->whereIn('season', $seasons);
            })
            ->orderBy('begin_date','desc')->orderBy('activity_name','asc')
            ->paginate($this->items_on_page);
```

the ->whereIn() could not process the "DB::raw('LOWER(season)', $seasons)" as suggested.  If i want to make sure that the data in the [activities].[season] column, I will either have to make sure the seasons are input into the table in lower case, or do a ->select(DB:raw('LOWER(season)') in the SQL statement.  I like the first option.

thank you again for your input apokryfos